# extender Detail in instruments ( user class)

Tags: iphone

I am using instruments to detect memory leak in my app, and i can't not see the calsse of my app in the stack trace ( the classe with a have created to see whrere is the leak). how i can show this in the stack trace of my extended detail. ???

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

On the instruments screen, next to the time, on top of "View" make sure you have selected the third button (the right panel). Once you see a stack on the right hand side of the window, go to the bottom and move the slider all the way to the right.